# jquery can't find richtextbox?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, find, textarea, richtextbox

I had a textarea box on a web form and was using some jquery code to set values and it was working great.  I changed the control to be a richtextbox .. well it renders it as such at least, and now the code can't find the control with jquery. Why?

rendered markup:

```
    </td></tr><tr><td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>BodyText</nobr></H3></td><td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody"><span dir="none">

            <span dir="ltr">
                <textarea name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$g_d63cd1e2_dcca_4553_8a0c_df6047a0a489$ff5_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField" rows="6" cols="20" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_d63cd1e2_dcca_4553_8a0c_df6047a0a489_ff5_1_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" title="BodyText" class="ms-long" dir="none"></textarea>
                <input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$g_d63cd1e2_dcca_4553_8a0c_df6047a0a489$ff5_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField_spSave" type="HIDDEN" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_d63cd1e2_dcca_4553_8a0c_df6047a0a489_ff5_1_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_spSave" />
```

if (browseris.ie5up && browseris.win32 && !IsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled()){RTE_ConvertTextAreaToRichEdit("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_d63cd1e2_dcca_4553_8a0c_df6047a0a489_ff5_1_ctl00_ctl00_TextField", true, false, "", "1033", null, null, null, null, null,"Compatible", "\u002fucharterror",null,null,null,null);}else{document.write(" 
Click for help about adding basic HTML formatting. 
");};

Here's the code I was using:

$('textarea[title$=BodyText]').val('hello');

Not sure if it matters, but it's being generated by SharePoint asp.net

Comment: Not sure if it fixes your problem but isn't BodyText supposed to be in quotes? http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Have you tried putting BodyText in double quotes? --> "BodyText"

Comment: tried that and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Put `BodyText` in quotes:

```
$('textarea[title$="BodyText"]').val('hello');
```

Comment: while tihs is clearly true and works... my code can't find the control .. http://jsfiddle.net/Hxt8R/13/

Comment: I'm not sure whether the jsfiddle textbox shows `hellox` for you, but it does for me. Perhaps your web browser has issues?

Comment: it shows it for me.. my problem is not in jsfiddle, only in sharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around BodyText.

```
$('textarea[title$="BodyText"]').val('hello');
```

Comment: tried and it did not work. $('textarea[title$="BodyText"]').val('hello');

Comment: not sure if related, but it looks like an RTE textbox.. controls ont top are blurred until I physically enter something. It's bound right and works otherwise. What's funny is I have original textarea stillon the form and the val works for it just fine at the same time.   $('textarea[title$=Message]').val(bodyprefixes[0]);